# Перевод байтов в строки и обратно

Tags: python, кодировка, шифрование, пароль

Пишу для себя софт с простеньким интерфейсом с полем вывода (Python 3.8), который будет генерить рандомные пароли для различных соцсетей и тд. После генерации использую шифровщик из пакета Crypto и сохраняю набор байт в строку в файл таким образом:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

cipher = AES.new(entered_key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_ECB)

pass = str(cipher.encrypt(pad(generated_password.encode('utf-8'), BLOCK_SIZE)))

input = "resource^login^pass".
```

где entered_key - введенный пользователем ключ-"сид", по которому можно будет потом декодировать, generated_pass - результат выполнения генерации пароля в строковом формате (напр. "p5:({Dfv;674"), а BLOCK_SIZE = 32. Я также использую функцию pad из этого пакета для того, чтобы заполнить строку до 32 знаков, чтобы можно было использовать этот шифровщик.

В pass'е хранится строка из зашифрованного в байтах пароля.

В текстовом файле оно хранится в таком виде:

```
input = VK^my_email@gmail.com^b'\xe4>\x1dN\x90\xe2H5\xce\xa8\xb8\x85\x03\x86\x17\xa6\x05\x01\x87\xa0\xcd\xe5\xa9\x87,\xba\xb0\x91\xabs\xe5S'
```

Потом я начал думать над тем, как это расшифровывать и выводить на экран. В итоге долгие попытки танцев с бубном над кодировками и у меня ни черта не получилось. То есть проблема состоит в том, чтобы из строковой переменной, в которой хранится байтовое представление пароля, сделать ее байтовой, декодировать и вывести на экран как строку.

На выходе я открываю файл, в котором сохранил строку, спличу ее по '^' и достаю элемент с индексом 2, т.е. - достаю pass. А потом я уже стараюсь что-нибудь сделать, чтобы расшифровать:

```
decipher = AES.new(entered_key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_ECB)
text = openfile.read().split('^')
pass = text[2]
```

Теперь в pass'e мы имеем строку:

```
pass = "b'\xe4>\x1dN\x90\xe2H5\xce\xa8\xb8\x85\x03\x86\x17\xa6\x05\x01\x87\xa0\xcd\xe5\xa9\x87,\xba\xb0\x91\xabs\xe5S'"
```

И вот надо как-то эту строку перевести правильно в байты, чтобы можно было использовать следующее:

```
decrypted_pass = decipher.decrypt(pass)
unpadded_decrypted_pass=unpad(decrypted_pass, BLOCK_SIZE)
```

Я пробовал преобразовывать эту строку pass разными способами:

```
bytes_pass = bytes(pass, encoding='utf-8')

bytes_pass = pass[2:-1].encode('utf-8') #делаю срез, чтобы не было в начале b' и в конце '

bytes_pass = pass.encode('utf-8')

bytes_pass = bytes(map(ord, pass))
и другие варианты.
```

И ничего из этого не давало мне нужного результата. В некоторых случаях у меня в переменной bytes_pass хранилось:

```
b"b'\\xe4>\\x1dN\\x90\\xe2H5\\xce\\xa8\\xb8\\x85\\x03\\x86\\x17\\xa6\\x05\\x01\\x87\\xa0\\xcd\\xe5\\xa9\\x87,\\xba\\xb0\\x91\\xabs\\xe5S'"
```

А в некоторых:

b'\xe4>\x1dN\x90\xe2H5\xce\xa8\xb8\x85\x03\x86\x17\xa6\x05\x01\x87\xa0\xcd\xe5\xa9\x87,\xba\xb0\x91\xabs\xe5S'

Если у кого-то есть идеи, как это можно грамотно обработать, чтобы получить в итоге исходную записанную в файл рандомно сгенерированную строку, то велкам. Либо может у кого-то есть решение проблемы кодирования любой строки по какому-то ключу (знаете, как в играх с процедурной генерацией, то есть каждый мог бы поиграть на той же карте, что и другой, если у него есть ключ(сид), вот только зашифровать и расшифровывать по нему), сохранением в текстовый файл с возможностью достать это и расшифровать обратно. Я пробовал использовать также и fernet, но там используется каждый раз соль, которая итак рандомно генерит. И расшифровать таким образом не получится, если только не хранить соль в файле и подтягивать ее, но тогда безопасность ставится под вопрос.

Comment: Вам не нужно массив байт в виде строки представлять, чтобы потом делать вещи типа `pass[2:-1].encode('utf-8') #делаю срез, чтобы не было в начале b' и в конце'`. Массив байт можно кодировать в HEX или base64

Answer (score 0):

В принципе нет ничего невыполнимого.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
import ast

entered_key = "123456"
generated_password = "QwErTyПаРоЛь"

cipher = AES.new(pad(entered_key.encode('utf-8'), AES.block_size), AES.MODE_ECB)
psw = str(cipher.encrypt(pad(generated_password.encode('utf-8'), AES.block_size)))

input = f"resource^login^{psw}"

# проворачиваем фарш назад :)
ppp = input.split("^", 2)[2]
decoded_ppp = ast.literal_eval(ppp)

stored_password = unpad(cipher.decrypt(decoded_ppp), AES.block_size).decode('utf-8')
print(stored_password)
```

Но проще просто сохранять через шестнадцатиричное представление.

```
...
psw = cipher.encrypt(pad(generated_password.encode('utf-8'), AES.block_size)).hex()

input = f"resource^login^{psw}"

ppp = input.split("^", 2)[2]
decoded_ppp = bytes.fromhex(ppp)
...
```